# Best measure to indicate quality of LDA model

Tags: topic-model, lda, perplexity, coherence

On my corpora, I am running LDA with different settings (I experiment with different number of topics, different different ngrams and TFIDF or regular BOW).

Now, I want to rank these setups to select one best topic model to continue working with.

In order to rank them, I have calculated both the coherence value as well as the perplexity for all the different settings, as is done [here](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python/#9createbigramandtrigrammodels). In the link, the number of topics is selected using the coherence value. However, a rationale for why coherence is chosen is missing.

Therefore, I have a few questions: are there more common measures for this task? What are likely reasons for picking one of these metrics over the other?